# Django user generated Groups

Tags: django

I am interested to know if one can extend the built in django groups. From what I have read it is for predefined groups with permissions. What I am trying to achieve is if user wants to for example create a group for fishing and another one for rock climbing; That user will send invites and receive joining requests. So they can make any group they like but that groups content is private. If Django does not offer this built in , is there a package anyone knows of. (difficult searching for this as one get django build in group search results).

I know its not the best question but any help and direction would be great .

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: If one can extend the prebuilt groups in django and if not what packages there are to achieve this if any. I have an idea of how to build this with a permissions system , but im relatively new to django and also know known packages will be better than i can code it.  If this is known off hand by a community member that would help. Like I said not the best question but has much value 2 me. thank you

Comment: You *could* extend Django's Group model but i would not do so and rather build a custom logic that covers your needs. Groups in Django belong more to the authentication part, like the User model.  
So you e.g. could create a `Community` model that handles your logic. (And, if needed, use the built-in Groups to handle permissions about *who* has permissions to create/edit/delete *Communities*)

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Was not sure if i was on the right path...